# unit testing for initialization in r

Tags: r, unit-testing

Suppose I have some internal object that is constructed inside a function that I want to write tests for.  For example I'm inside some function, and I need to create a dataframe which I then use only inside the function.  i.e. Once the function is done running, the dataframe is gone.  How do I test if such a dataframe internal to a function is initialized properly?

I can't "get at" this internal dataframe from outside the function, yet I would still like to run a test to make sure it's initialized correctly.  Essentially I want to be in debug mode for the function so I can view the workspace inside the function and run a unit test there.

Should I be writing a separate constructor type function for this dataframe alone (in which case I can easily write such a test)?  Or is there a way to suspend a function from completing and to work with the workspace inside the function right before it returns?  (like being in the last step of debug mode for the function)

Any general advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not really a unit testing expert but don't you usually not want to test these types of things?  Shouldn't you just be testing the output of the actual function itself.  That way if you decide one day to completely rework how the function is coded you don't have to worry about if it will pass a test related to code that only mattered for your old implementation.  Test the public interface and test it hard - but don't worry about the internals.

Comment: The problem is the public interface consists of basically one function, and everything is essentially internal.  I'm writing a model fitting package where on the surface the user will be able to fit the model, predict with the model, and plot.  Inside the model fitting function there is a lot to check obviously.  Much of it is separated out into functions which can be individually tested, but part of the fitting process involves constructing certain dataframes (inside the main model fitting function) which I'd like to be able to test as described above, essentially in some type of debug mode.

Comment: I think that my issue is trying to tell me that I probably need to write separate constructor functions for these internal dataframes!

Comment: How about adding `dbg=TRUE` to the list of arguments to your function, and internally, `if(dbg) save.image(your_data_frame)`  ?  Also see `base::trace`  and `utils::debugger` .

Comment: "Much of it [stuff that needs testing] is separated out into functions which can be individually tested": please explain why you cannot separate the construction of the data.frame as well?

Comment: I certainly can cbeleites, part of the question is should I?  I thought that this might be a common issue in R, but as I was saying, maybe it's just an issue with myself poorly designing the over-arching function!